# Insert an item into an already sorted datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a data table whose defaultview.sort is already set, and the datatable is filled with data, what I am trying to do is add a row to the datatable, but i need this row to always be the first row, and the rest of the table to be sorted normaly, here is my code:

```
//Sort the datatable
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "DisplayFiled";

//Add the fixed row
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["ValueField"] = String.Empty;
dr["DisplayField"] = "All";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by adding a 2nd column to sort on

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("UserAdded",typeof(bool));
dt.Columns.Add("DisplayField", typeof(int));

DataView vw = new DataView(dt);
vw.Sort = "[UserAdded] desc, [DisplayField] asc";
```

When you add a row you set UserAdded = true to force it to show up first

```
var manualRow = dt.Rows.NewRow();
manualRow["UserAdded"] = true;
manualRow["ValueField"] = String.Empty;
manualRow["DisplayField"] = "All";
```

Comment: Other answers are true, but I found this the most clever idea, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass throught the sorted table and copy records to a non-sorted table with first record "All".

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? Like you force the table to sort only once, and all new records added are kept in their position

Answer (score 0):

create another instance of DataTable. Add the row you wanted at top and add rows of sorted table to newly created datatable.

```
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    // fill dt
    System.Data.DataTable dtNew = new System.Data.DataTable();
    System.Data.DataRow dr = dtNew.NewRow();
    dr["ValueField"] = String.Empty;
    dr["DisplayField"] = "All";
    dtNew.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
    {
        dtNew.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Datatable.Copy() it will maintain your previous sorting, but not apply it to the new row.

```
Dim DT As DataTable = GetDTfromsomewhere()
Dim View As DataView = DT.DefaultView()
View.Sort = "SomeColumn"

DT = DT.Copy

Dim Row = DT.NewRow()
Row.Item(0) = 0
Row.Item(1) = "All"
DT.Rows.InsertAt(Row, 0)
```